# brasero video project error

Tags: brasero

Brasero will not burn video projects. The error message says:

All required applications and libraries are not installed.
Please install the following manually and try again:
mplex (GStreamer plugin),
vcdimager (application)

I cannot find the mplex plugin - how do I install this?

Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: Which Ubuntu release? Which version of Brasero? How did you install it?

Comment: Version 19.04 of course